# DevExpress: обновление страницы через popup-контрол

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, devexpress

На странице есть `input-text id='textID'` и `img-картинка`, по нажатию на которую открывается `ASPxPopupControl`-окошко.

Там есть ссылки, и мы должны **по нажатию** на любую ссылку из popup'a **обновить значение** `input-text id='textID'`.

JQuery не помогает - просто не находит `input-text` (пишет [] в консоли и все), то же и с простым js.

**Есть идеи, как это можно сделать?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как оно заработало:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('<controlID>').value = NewValue;
```